# React-Flow passing return values of a function as props

Tags: reactjs, properties, flowtype

flow in complaining about this:

```
callMe(input: string): number | string | string[]
{
  // return stuff
}
...
render(){
  return(
    <MyComponent items={this.callMe("values")} />
  )
}
```

Flow says: "props of React element MyComponent (This type is incompatible with object type Property 'items' is incompatible:)"

The items-props of MyComponent is defined as string[].

This code is working (even if it's quite ugly atm). So flow thinks that I want to pass the hole function (or class?) am I right?

Is there a way to correct flow about this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

After seperating my callMe() function, flow isn't complaining anymore. It just seems that flow can't handle multiple possible return types.